# Проблема с доступом к беспроводному сегменту в Cisco Packet Tracer

Tags: сеть, router, cisco-packet-tracer, linksys

[image: фрагмент сети]

Пинг с устройств в беспроводном сегменте (PC7, Laptop и Laptop0) проходит на остальные хосты. А при попытке пинга с хостов вне этого сегмента (PC0, PC1 и РС2) пакет доходит только до Linksys-WRT300M, где обрывается. У меня есть предположение, что это происходит из-за протокола NAT(т.е. я могу зайти в интернет, а интернет не может зайти ко мне), но точно не уверен. Выполняю работу в рамках курса Cisco в универе, так что не особо разбираюсь пока.

Можно ли получить доступ к PC7 и Laptop извне беспроводного сегмента?